# Set variables in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In my **build.gradle** (*Module: app*) I specified one `buildConfigField` and one `resValue` variable.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        buildConfigField "String", "APP_EXP_DATE", "\"DEC 31 23:59:59 EDT 2018\""
        resValue         "String", "app_exp_date", "\"DEC 31 23:59:59 EDT 2018\""
    }
}
```

Then I expected them to use in my Java code like this:

```
BuildConfig.APP_EXP_DATE
R.string.app_exp_date
```

but unfortunately I am experiencing the following errors:

> error: cannot find symbol variable APP_EXP_DATE
>
> error: illegal start of type

How can I make it work to be able to access variables from gradle in my Java code?

Comment: I use just `release` buildType, no `debug` buildType, but that should not cause any issues.

Comment: I think it probably does. Even if you don't use debug, Android Studio doesn't know that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have some options:

1. Define your strings and values under defaultConfig as follow:

   ```
   android {
       // your code
       defaultConfig {
           // your code
           resValue "string", "<key>", "<value>" 
           buildConfigField "string", "<key>", "<value>"
           // ...
       }
       // your code
   }
   ```
2. You can put your string in both Release and Debug type

   ```
   buildTypes {
       release {
           // your code
           resValue "string", "<key>", "<value>" 
           buildConfigField "string", "<key>", "<value>"
           // ...
       }
       debug {
           // your code 
           resValue "string", "<key>", "<value>" 
           buildConfigField "string", "<key>", "<value>"
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this help!

Comment: There are some packages having same BuildConfig, are you sure that you have chosen your project one? Also you are getting same error as in your question?

Comment: I found the problem. The `buildConfigField` has to be defined in module's `build.gradle`, not the app's one.

Comment: Perfect! I am happy for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make it work to be able to access variables from gradle in
>   my Java code?

The issue in your codes seems to be using in `release` buildType which might cause the issue (not resolving it.

But, this is how it should be :

In `gradle.properties`:

```
ExpDate="DEC 31 23:59:59 EDT 2018"
```

In `app/Build.gradle` (*Note that it should be in android block code*):

```
def APP_EXP_DATE = '"' + ExpDate + '"' ?: '"Define Expire Date"'
android.buildTypes.each { type -> 
    type.buildConfigField 'String', 'APP_EXP_DATE', ExpDate

}
```

**Usage:**

```
BuildConfig.APP_EXP_DATE
```

As a `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(activity, BuildConfig.APP_EXP_DATE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I experience same error message with your solution.

Comment: Sorry! I was editing the answer. Please check that again. Just made changes to be exactly like yours.

Comment: Are you still using those codes inside `buildTypes` block? Because I have just made an edit and it should be **in android block code** and separated from those `buildTypes`.

Comment: All my `ext.` variables are defined in my project's `build.gradle`. That part is working fine for a very long time.

Comment: I have removed all `ext.` variables and used direct inputs ... and there is no change - same error

Comment: I'm thinking about where you can see **the dependencies** and *that should probably be the place to put the codes inside*. I imagine, that should be player or base project and not this `Build.gradle` and that's why you get the error and it should be directly using inside the project `build.gradle`. However, Just checked & codes working fine.

Comment: Even Lint Analysis says *"Assignment is not used"* for `def APP_EXP_DATE` line. So maybe it is ignored and not compiled at all.